# Swift generics - cannot convert value to type

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have an issue with generics in swift.

I am building simple http client and I want to extend it to add caching. I've build cache solution using this excellent post [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/caching-in-swift/).

I want to be able to pass cache instance to my client when it is initialised so it needs to be able to hold different data types that conform to `Codable`.

Here's what I've got so far (cache implementation is as described in article):

data:

```swift
struct CountryResult: Codable {
    let meta: Meta //confroms to Codable
    let results: [Country] //conforms to Codable
}
```

cache:

```swift
final class Cache<Key: Hashable, Value> {
// cache implementation
}

// MARK: - Codable

extension Cache.Entry: Codable where Key: Codable, Value: Codable {}
extension Cache: Codable where Key: Codable, Value: Codable {
    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()

        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let entries = try container.decode([Entry].self)
        entries.forEach(insert)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(keyTracker.keys.compactMap(entry))
    }
}
```

http client:

```swift
struct HttpService {

    let service: BaseUrl
    let cache: Cache<URL, Codable>

    init(service: String = "https://some.service/api", cache: Cache<URL, Codable> = Cache()) {
        self.service = service
        self.cache = cache
    }

    // performs http get
    func get<T: Codable>(endpoint: String, completion: @escaping (T?, Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = buildUrl(endpoint) else {
            print("Invalid url")
            return
        }

        if let cachedData = cache[url] as? T {
            print("Cache hit for: \(url)")
            completion(cachedData, nil)
            return
        } else {
            print("Cache miss for: \(url)")
        }

        //data not in cache, go to network
        //....
    }
```

Now, I want to be able to instantiate this http client in different view controllers that will request different datatypes. I also want to persist each VC cache separately, so when initialising VC I am trying to find if cache was stored to disk and load it like so:

```swift
let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let cacheUrl = urls[0].appendingPathComponent("/v1/test.cache")
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: cacheUrl) {
    let cache  = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Cache<URL, CountryResult>.self, from: data) ?? Cache<URL, CountryResult>()
    let httpClient = HttpService(service: "https://some.service/api", cache: cache) //ERROR
}
```

But I am getting following error, which I do not fully understand:
`Cannot convert value of type 'Cache<URL, CountryResult>?' to expected argument type 'Cache<URL, Codable>' (aka 'Cache<URL, Decodable & Encodable>')`

Why it cannot be converted if `CountryResult` confroms to `Codable` aka `Decodable & Encodable`

Comment: Show your Cache declaration. The Cache on the link doesn't conform to Codable

Comment: It does via extension, I've updated post

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear. Your `HttpService` expects a parameter of type `Cache<URL, Codable>`, but you are giving it `Cache<URL, CountryResult>`. Generics are (what's called) "invariant", so these two types are considered different types

Answer (score 2):

If you change the below code

```
let cache: Cache<URL, Codable>
```

as

```
let cache: Cache<URL,T: Codable>
```

in HttpService struct, hope it will work.

According to [Swift doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/GenericParametersAndArguments.html), In Generics, it is allowed to have type parameter conforming to class or protocol or protocol composition but not just protocol.